# Referenced file contains errors (http://testng.org/testng-1.0.dtd)

Tags: xml, eclipse, dtd

I have installed TestNG plugin in eclipse still I see the below error
**Referenced file contains errors (http://testng.org/testng-1.0.dtd). For more information, right click on the message in the Problems View and select "Show Details..."**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE suite SYSTEM "http://testng.org/testng-1.0.dtd" >
<suite name="PVAI-Document">
    <test name="document-module">
        <packages>
            <package name="com.genpact.pvai.document.*" />
        </packages>
    </test>
</suite>
```

Comment: What happens when you go to the **Problems** view and do as it asks? Can you right-click on the file and have it revalidated?

Comment: It displays **Details information is currently unavailable. Please re-validate the file to regenerate the error details**

Answer (score 11):

I solved it by adding the secure flag in the URL as follows:
"http**s**://testng.org/testng-1.0.dtd"

Regards.

Answer (score 1):

The answer from @Nahuel is correct, it's fixed by changing the URL to https. But I think it worth mention that this is a problem of Eclipse not following redirect (302) responses (at least in this case)

As you can see below if I use postman to query the URL the server responds with a 302 redirect to the https version

[image: postman-request-for-dtd]

Answer (score 0):

I solved it be removing the letter 's' in the http**s**://testng.org/testng-1.0.dtd